# JQuery combine .append and .attr

Tags: jquery, append, attr

I want to combine .append and .attr. How I should do correctly?

```
$('.ngg-gallery-thumbnail').append("<a href='add/"+attr("data-title")+"/' class='btn btn-default'>Add</a>");
```

I want to make something like this in .ngg-gallery-thumbnail:

```
<a href='add/brown-shoose/' class='btn btn-default'>Add</a>
```

Full .ngg-gallery-thumbnail tag looks like:

```html
<div class="ngg-gallery-thumbnail">
  <a href="/wp-content/gallery/lietuviskos-kepures/LT-3002VV-6-mm-800-gm2-100-wool.jpg"
    title=""
    data-src="/wp-content/gallery/lietuviskos-kepures/LT-3002VV-6-mm-800-gm2-100-wool.jpg"
    data-thumbnail="/wp-content/gallery/lietuviskos-kepures/thumbs/thumbs_LT-3002VV-6-mm-800-gm2-100-wool.jpg"
    data-image-id="474"
    data-title="LT 3002VV 6 mm, 800 gm2 100 % wool"
    data-description=""
    data-image-slug="lt-3002vv-6-mm-800-gm2-100-wool"
    class="ngg-fancybox"
    rel="928d7ca69950d6ca6a0cf7cad40d2edf">
      <img title="LT 3002VV 6 mm, 800 gm2 100 % wool"
           alt="LT 3002VV 6 mm, 800 gm2 100 % wool"
           src="/wp-content/gallery/lietuviskos-kepures/thumbs/thumbs_LT-3002VV-6-mm-800-gm2-100-wool.jpg"
           style="max-width:100%;"
           width="240"
           height="160" />
  </a>
  <div style="max-width: 240px;">LT 3002VV 6 mm, 800 gm2 100 % wool</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Is this happening on document load? In response to a user-event? Where does the `data-title` attribute come from? Are you iterating over existing elements or are you programmatically adding elements from somewhere else?

Answer (score 0):

You should use `appendTo()` function in order to  get this done.

Please check below example :

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
 $("<a href='add/brown-shoose' class='btn btn-default'>Add</a>").appendTo($('.ngg-gallery-thumbnail'));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<div class="ngg-gallery-thumbnail">
 <a href="/wp-content/gallery/lietuviskos-kepures/LT-3002VV-6-mm-800-gm2-100-wool.jpg" title="" data-src="/wp-content/gallery/lietuviskos-kepures/LT-3002VV-6-mm-800-gm2-100-wool.jpg" data-thumbnail="/wp-content/gallery/lietuviskos-kepures/thumbs/thumbs_LT-3002VV-6-mm-800-gm2-100-wool.jpg" data-image-id="474" data-title="LT 3002VV                6 mm, 800 gm2 100 % wool" data-description="" data-image-slug="lt-3002vv-6-mm-800-gm2-100-wool" class="ngg-fancybox" rel="928d7ca69950d6ca6a0cf7cad40d2edf">
  <img title="LT 3002VV 6 mm, 800 gm2 100 % wool" alt="LT 3002VV                6 mm, 800 gm2 100 % wool" src="/wp-content/gallery/lietuviskos-kepures/thumbs/thumbs_LT-3002VV-6-mm-800-gm2-100-wool.jpg" style="max-width:100%;" width="240" height="160">
 </a>
 <div style="max-width: 240px;">LT 3002VV 6 mm, 800 gm2 100 % wool</div>
</div>
```